# Back button crashes after pushing a new view on iOS 13

Tags: xcode, ios13, xcode11

I have an app works perfect on iOS 12. I wanted to test on iOS 13, XCode 11. I push one view controller to another with storyboard navigation segue. When I press back button (default back button) on second page, the app crashes and produces error below. It happens in every navigation page, even empty views.

```
2019-08-28 14:10:48.632540+0300 App Name[28453:400531] *** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController _popNavigationBar:item:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3899.13.11/UINavigationController.m:8520
2019-08-28 14:10:48.642352+0300 App Name[28453:400531] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Override of -navigationBar:shouldPopItem: returned YES after manually popping a view controller (navigationController=<UINavigationController: 0x7fa22f0de000>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afdbde __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5015cb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afd958 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff255506f5 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46812310 -[UINavigationController _popNavigationBar:item:] + 379
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46592209 -[UINavigationBar _sendNavigationPopForBackBarButtonItem:] + 277
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff465bf771 -[_UINavigationBarContentView __backButtonAction:] + 58
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f0abc1 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468fc3e5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468fc72f -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 398
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468fc892 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 753
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468fb68e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 481
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f450c7 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2604
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f469ce -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4596
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f2204f -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46fa18c0 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 6847
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46fa4386 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5980
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23a60ac1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23a609ec __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23a601c4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23a5aecf __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23a5a6b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38016bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f0990f UIApplicationMain + 1621
    24  App Name                           0x000000010691b810 main + 112
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff50fe1cf5 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: did you Override `shouldPopItem` delegate of UINavigationBar?

Comment: I just did and added UINavigationControllerDelegate,UINavigationBarDelegate. But shouldPopItem is not called.

Comment: Hey, did U find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom class of `UINavigationController` and then add `UINavigationBarDelegate` as below and asign that class to your `UINavigationController`

```
 class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationBar.delegate = self
    }
}

extension MyNavigationController : UINavigationBarDelegate {
    public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: now it doesn't crash. but not poping the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an issue for you, but I had a similar thing (actually my issue was that it worked perfectly on ios13 but on ios12 the back button didn't work).

The error tells you that you can't manually pop the viewcontroller and also then return true (ie yes you should pop the viewController) so you need to return false if you manually pop

```
override public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        popViewController(animated: true)
        return false
    }
```